# File upload with el-upload and axios, no progress bar

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, element-ui

I have created file uploader with element ui and axios. but there is no progress bar to display the progress of uploaded file.

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <h1>My Cards</h1>
    <el-button type="primary" icon="el-icon-upload" @click="uploadDialogVisible = true">Import CSV</el-button>
    <Pagination
      :total="totalCards"
      layout="total, prev, pager, next"
      :limit="10"
      :page.sync="currentPage"
      @pagination="loadNewPage"
    ></Pagination>
    <el-table v-loading="loadingCardsList" :data="cards" stripe style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="name" sortable label="Product Name"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="description" label="Description" width="200px"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="price" label="Price"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="cardcategory" sortable label="Category"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Operations" width="300px">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button size="mini" type="primary" @click="handleView(scope.$index, scope.row)">View</el-button>
          <el-button size="mini" @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Edit</el-button>
          <el-button size="mini" type="danger" @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Delete</el-button>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
    <el-dialog :visible.sync="viewCard" width="30%">
      <el-card class="box-card">
        <h1>{{currentViewedCard.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{currentViewedCard.description}}</p>
        <p>{{currentViewedCard.price}}</p>
        <el-tag>{{currentViewedCard.cardcategory}}</el-tag>
      </el-card>
    </el-dialog>
    <el-dialog
      title="Import Data from CSV"
      :visible.sync="uploadDialogVisible"
      :before-close="handleUploadDialogClose"
    >
      <div>
        <el-upload
          class="upload-demo"
          action=""
          :on-change="handleUploadChange"
          :before-upload="handleBeforeUpload"
          accept=".csv"
          :file-list="fileList"
          ref="upload"
          :auto-upload="false"
          :on-progress="handleProgress"
          :on-success="handleSuccess"
        >
          <el-button slot="trigger" size="small" type="primary">Click to upload</el-button>
          <el-button
            style="margin-left: 10px;"
            size="small"
            type="success"
            @click="submitUpload"
          >upload to server</el-button>
          <div slot="tip" class="el-upload__tip">jpg/png files with a size less than 500kb</div>
        </el-upload>
      </div>
    </el-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Resource from '@/api/resource';
import Pagination from '@/components/Pagination/index.vue';
const cardcategoryResource = new Resource('cardcategories');
const cardResource = new Resource('cards');
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Cards',
  components: {
    Pagination,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [],
      categories: [],
      currentPage: '',
      totalCards: '',
      loadingCardsList: true,
      currentViewedCard: '',
      viewCard: false,
      uploadDialogVisible: false,
      fileList: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getCardCategories();
    this.getCardList({ page: 1 });
  },
  methods: {
    submitUpload() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('csvfile', this.fileList[0].raw);
      axios
        .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/csvupload', formData)
        .then(() => {
          this.$message.success('Success');
          this.getCardList({ page: 1 });
          // this.fileList = []; //Temporary depicts that the file has been uploaded
        })
        .catch(() => {
          alert('error');
        });
    },
    handleProgress(ev, file, fileLIst) {
      file.raw['status'] = "uploading";
    },
    handleSuccess(res, file, fileLIst) {
      file.raw['status'] = "success";
    },
    handleUploadChange(file, fileList) {
      this.fileList = fileList.slice(-1);
    },
    handleBeforeUpload(file) {
      const allowedCsvMime = [
        'text/csv',
        'text/plain',
        'application/csv',
        'text/comma-separated-values',
        'application/excel',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'application/vnd.msexcel',
        'text/anytext',
        'application/octet-stream',
        'application/txt',
      ];
      if (allowedCsvMime.includes(file.type)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.$message.error(
          'You can only upload CSV files. No other file types are allowed'
        );
        this.fileList.pop(file);
      }
    },
    async getCardList(query) {
      this.loadingCardsList = true;
      const data = await cardResource.list(query);
      this.cards = data.data;
      for (const card of this.cards) {
        card['cardcategory'] = this.getCategoryName(card.cardCategory_id);
      }
      console.log(this.cards);
      this.totalCards = data.total;
      this.loadingCardsList = false;
    },
    async getCardCategories() {
      this.categories = await cardcategoryResource.list({});
      console.log(this.categories);
    },
    loadNewPage(val) {
      this.getCardList({ page: val.page });
    },
    getCategoryName(id) {
      return this.categories[id - 1].name;
    },
    handleView(index, info) {
      this.viewCard = true;
      this.currentViewedCard = info;
    },
    handleEdit(index, info) {
      this.$router.push('/cards/edit/' + info.id);
    },
    closeDialog() {
      this.viewProduct = false;
      this.currentProductInfo = null;
    },
    handleDelete(index, info) {
      cardResource.destroy(info.id).then(response => {
        this.$message({
          message: 'Card Deleted Successfully',
          type: 'success',
          duration: 3000,
        });
        this.getCardList({ page: this.currentPage });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

In this i have used el-upload component to upload file and submited the file with axios wia btn click. The file gets uploaded but there is no way to see the progress bar and the green success icon after successfull upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide onUploadProgress as parameter in axios.post.
Create one progress bar and provide value of uploadPercentage to it.
Example.

````
axios.post( 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/csvupload',
   formData,
   {
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     },
     onUploadProgress: function( progressEvent ) {
       this.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded * 100 ) / progressEvent.total ) );
     }.bind(this)
   }
 ).then(function(){
   console.log('SUCCESS!!');
 })
 .catch(function(){
   console.log('FAILURE!!');
 });
},```
````